# C++ problematic code piece

Tags: c++

We got practice sheets for a test next week, for studying a little bit of C++ (still a beginner here). I still can't figure out a simple question.

That is, why are these snippets of code problematic?

```
 int& p(int z) { return  z; }
 int* h(int z) { return &z; }
```

Comment: Think about the lifetime of `z`. When is `z` a valid object? What can we do with the return of those functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `int *h(int z) {return &z}` is called, the parameter passed to the function is **copied** to a variable named `z`. That copy only lasts as long as the function. So once the function returns, it is no longer available to your program. So you can't have a valid pointer to it once the function returns: formally `&z` is invalidated.

The same is true for the *reference* version `int &p(int z) {return z}`.

As an exercise, see if you can figure out what would happen if `z` was itself a *reference*: i.e.  `int &p(int& z) {return z}`. Then, a copy would not be taken. But do note that no professional would ever write a function like this.

Comment: Your exercise may is still problematic.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of the returned value is undefined.The tricky thing here is that if you test your function with some kind of operation ( eg. printing to std output or assertion) you might often get an expected result but that doesn't mean it is safe since returned value is pointing to value written in the stack which could be wiped out at any given moment right after the function returns ( it is called stack unwinding). So, the rule of thumb is, don't return the address or reference to a locally defined variable of a function unless it was defined as static and why on earth would one prefer that unless situations force you? :-)

Comment: More of a "Rule of keeping your job" rather than a "rule of thumb". Plus one though.

Answer (score -7):

Both snippets pass a reference (or pointer in the second case) to temporary. Consider for example `p(18)`. Where would 18 actually be stored? So where should `p(18)` point to?

Side note: If everything would be const, the code would be ok, ie.

```
int const & p(int const & input) { return input; }
```

The standard would guarantee it.

Comment: Your side note is not true, you'd still get a dangling reference/pointer.

Comment: Maybe the note was misleading at first. I've clarified it. It is correct.

Comment: The `const` qualification of a type is unrelated to whether or not it's a reference type.

Comment: Yes, but it increases the lifetime of `18` in `p(18)`. Whats your point?

Comment: They *return*, not pass, a reference (or a pointer). The reference (or pointer) is not to a temporary but to the parameter.

Comment: @m8mble: His point is that you didn't just add `const`: you made `input` a reference in the case that the function returns a reference. In the question, it wasn't. That's the key point you're _trying_ to make, and it has nothing to do with the `const`ness. The `18` there _already_ lasts for the duration of the function call.

Comment: I know, that I've added `const &`. My point is, that doing `res = p(18)` prolongs lifetime of this very `18` until `res` dies.

Comment: @m8mble Returning a const reference doesn't extend the lifetime of anything. If a temporary is created for the parameter, you're still left with a dangling reference. You're thinking of binding a reference to a temporary (`const T& x = function_returning_T()`) which is a different thing.